# how to connect scala applet with html file?

Tags: swing, scala, applet

Im trying to make a simple scala applet from the following code:

```
import javax.swing._
object ScalaAppletMain extends JApplet{
val sa = new App
override def init(){
    val pane = getContentPane()
    pane.add("Center",sa)
}
override def start(){}
override def stop(){}
}
```

(please note that this code is heavily relaying on web examples and im only trying to learn how to do it)
and the app class:

```
import javax.swing._
import java.awt._
class App extends JPanel {
    var number = 2229999
  initialize()

  private def initialize() {
   var text = new JLabel(number.toString)
   var panel = new JPanel()
  panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,1))
  panel.add(text)
  add(panel)
}}
```

and the code for my html file:

```
<applet>
    archive="ScalaAppletMain.class,app.class,scala-library.jar"
    width="660"
    height="500"
</applet>
```

however it doesnt work, any help please?

Comment: You know that there is also the `scala.App` trait defined and always imported?

Comment: Perhaps you might like to explain in what way it doesn't work. In particular, does your browser's console give any error messages?

Comment: it just doesnt load, the java applet window opens but nothin happens

Answer (score 1):

For a start the applet element should have the attributes inside the opening tag not the body.

```
<applet
    archive="ScalaAppletMain.class,app.class,scala-library.jar"
    width="660"
    height="500">
</applet>
```

Then, to find any other issues, you're going to have to find the console output for your Java applet environment and look to see if it is logging any errors - they should give you a clue.

For example on the Mac, the Java Preferences app has an (Advanced) option to show the console when an Applet is loaded.

Comment: Then TELL US WHAT THE CONSOLE OUTPUT SAYS.

Comment: Why 2 answers?  The content of your other answer would be best edited into this answer, then deleted.  +1 for noticing the malformed HTML & stressing the console output.  Without the console output, we can only guess.

Comment: Because I originally posted the console answer, then noticed the tag. So I replaced the console version with this, expecting it to be the solution. When it wasn't it seemed to me best to have another shot in another answer - but I'll amalgamate.